# How do I set a color filter on a drawable which will be used in a RemoteView?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-notifications, remoteview, android-remoteview

I have an `ImaveView` on a `RemoteView` for which I have to apply a filter. When not in the `RemoteView` this is what I do and it works well:

```
    Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    icon.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    image.setImageDrawable(icon);
```

The `RemoteView` does not appear to have a method for me to set a drawable that is not a resource. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Below code worked for RemoteViews which is ImageView in Home screen widget for changing tint color.
Tested on device running with API Level 29

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.myRemoteViewId, "setColorFilter", Color.parseColor("#000000"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. For me the solution was to use the bitmap. These two methods should give you the answer or at least some kind of solution.

```
private void setCurrentStatus(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap result = changeBitmapColor(source, Color.YELLOW);

    remoteViews.setBitmap(R.id.iv_icon, "setImageBitmap", result);
}

private Bitmap changeBitmapColor(Bitmap sourceBitmap, int color) {
    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0,
            sourceBitmap.getWidth() - 1, sourceBitmap.getHeight() - 1);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    ColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    p.setColorFilter(filter);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, 0, 0, p);

    return resultBitmap;
}
```

R.id.iv_icon - is the id of the ImageView from the layout

You can always get drawable from your ImageView and convert it to bitmap.

Comment: Is there also a "tint" solution, including in XML ?